# ActionView::Template::Error (no implicit conversion from nil to integer) - awesome_nested_set

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, nested, acts-as-nested-set

I'm using [awesome_nested_set](https://github.com/collectiveidea/awesome_nested_set) to implement nested pattern in select tag. When there is no record in the database form is loading successfully, but after adding first category as base category whose parent_id is null this error is showing up

```
ActionView::Template::Error (no implicit conversion from nil to integer)
```

I've used view helper to implement this, my select tag looks like this

```
<%= f.select :parent_id, nested_set_options(Category, @category) {|i, level| "#{'-' * level} #{i.name}" } %>
```

Please help, how to get rid of this error, I'm using awesome nested set to implement this!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use this:

```
<%= f.select :parent_id, nested_set_options(Category, @category) {|i| "#{'-' * i.level} #{i.name}" } %>
```

You have a serious error in your block. As documented on the gem's page, the block passed to the `nested_set_options` only accepts a single argument `i` which is the category itself. `level` is a method of `i` which you can get using `i.level`.